# Passing model property expression to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, generics, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to have a way of getting a view to focus on a particular model property from a controller in a generic way.

What i have so far is:

---

### Controller:

```
// To become an extension/base class method
private void FocusOnField<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> fieldExpression)
{
    ViewData["FieldToFocus"] = fieldExpression;
}

...

FocusOnField((ConcreteModelClass m) => m.MyProperty);
```

### View

```
    public static class ViewPageExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString FocusScript<TModel>(this ViewPage<TModel> viewPage)
        {
            if (viewPage.ViewData["FieldToFocus"] != null)
            {
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(
@"<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#" + viewPage.Html.IdFor((System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, object>>)viewPage.ViewData["FieldToFocus"]) + @"').focus();
        }, 500);
    });
</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

The problem I'm faced with now, is that in the view's `FocusScript` method I don't know the return type of the property to focus on, and casting to `(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, object>>)` fails for any property that doesn't return an object.

I can't just add a second generic parameter for the property because I don't know what the return type of the property the controller wants me to focus on is.

**How can I write my view extension method `FocusScript` in a generic way so it can be used with properties of varying return types?**

---

### Why is there a problem?

I know I could just pass the Id of the control i want to focus on in the controller and have javascript read that id, find the control and focus on it. However, I don't like having something that belongs in the view (the Id of a control) hard-coded in the controller. I want to tell the method what property I want and it should know the Id to use in the same way the view normally gets/creates the Id for a control.

Lets say I have a model:

```
class MyModel
{
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In different places in the controller I want to focus one different fields:

```
FocusOnField((MyModel m) => m.IntProperty);
...
FocusOnField((MyModel m) => m.StringProperty);
```

Now, in the first case the expression is a function returning an integer, in the second case it's returning a string. As a result I don't know what to cast my ViewData["FieldToFocus"] to (to pass it to `IdFor<>()`) as it varies based on the property..

Comment: would it work to do all the plumbing in a view model and type the view to that viewmodel?  then you could have access to the properties without worrying about the return type.

Comment: You mean have the method `FocusScript` in the Model? I'm still not sure how that would work since the controller could want to bind to a number of different properties on that model (with different return types). If you think it would work I'd appreciate a code example as maybe I'm not following correctly.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by varying return types and why you need to know this?

Comment: I ask because javascript focus() just needs to know the element to focus on rather than property info of the view-model class

Comment: Could you not do this unobtrusively?  For example, add, from your view, a `data-focus` attribute on the element on which you want to focus, and then have a generic script that focuses on this element on load?  You could probably even do this using a custom attribute, if you would rather do it on your model vs. the view, though I think this is a view concern, not a model or controller concern.

Comment: @JeradRose: That makes sense and would be pretty simple, however the field to focus on won't be the same for a given view every time. I.e. after one action I want to focus in one place, and after another I want to focus on another (even though it might be the same view that displays the result). This means having the Id/Field Name somewhere in the model (I guess) which means the controller sets it, which means it's either hard-coded in the controller, or I'm back to the original problem. Sorry if I've miss-understood.

Comment: Then perhaps an option would be to pass the name of the focused property in as another value in your model (`string FocusedProperty`), and then have an MVC template (if you're already using these, this would be even better) to check for this and render the `data-focus` attribute based on the value of FocusedProperty.  Maybe not a clean solution, but it's not a very clean problem you're trying to solve. :)

Comment: @JeradRose: I'm not sure what the code would look like when you say "check for this". For example, what happens if my view is displaying a list of (same-type) complex objects and I want to focus on a property of the 3rd in the list. I'm thinking my problem can probably be solved using reflection somewhere inside my `FocusScript` method to call `IdFor` with the correct generic parameters but I can't quite get my head around it.

Comment: I take it something as simple as this doesn't work? `viewPage.Html.IdFor(viewPage.ViewData["FieldToFocus"] as Expression)`

Comment: @mouters: Typed arguments can't be inferred from usage.

Comment: @JeradRose html5 already has the *autofocus* attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as using a LambdaExpression. No need to go the `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` way.

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static string IdFor(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        LambdaExpression expression
    )
    {
        var id = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        return htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(id);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString FocusScript(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper
    )
    {
        if (htmlHelper.ViewData["FieldToFocus"] != null)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(
            @"<script type=""text/javascript"">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#" + htmlHelper.IdFor((LambdaExpression)htmlHelper.ViewData["FieldToFocus"]) + @"').focus();
                    }, 500);
                });
            </script>");
        }
        else
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    FocusOnField((MyModel m) => m.IntProperty);
    return View(new MyModel());
}
```

and in your view:

```
@model MyModel

@Html.FocusScript()
```

This being said I am leaving without comment the fact that *a controller action is setting a focus*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll test and assuming it works accept and award the bounty. Why shouldn't a controller set the focus. Re controller setting focus, how/where should I set focus on a textbox (for example) after a particular action is completed (same view is used to display the result)?

Comment: Just looking and you're relying on a few asp.net 4 methods.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Disappointed that Darin has swooped in after my answer and taken the bounty - ah well at least my activity has sparked some interest and got you and answer. :)

Comment: @mouters: I was possibly too hasty - if I was using MVC4 IMO it's a better solution as it doesn't use reflection and appears less hacky. Saying that I'm not using MVC4 so this won't work as is. I'll review who to give the bounty to when it's ready to expire.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Actually I'm not suggestion this is a worse answer - it looks cleaner and looks more elegant.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett, there's nothing MVC4 specific in my answer. This will work in MVC3 as well.

Comment: I thought (from looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.templateinfo.getfullhtmlfieldid.aspx)) that `GetFullHtmlFieldId` was MVC4 only, but you're right. It does work.

Answer (score 5):

I think I've come up with a solution to your problem - it works in my environment but then I've had to guess how your code probably looks.

```
public static class ViewPageExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetIdFor<TViewModel, TProperty>(ViewPage<TViewModel> viewPage, Expression<Func<TViewModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return viewPage.Html.IdFor(expression);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString FocusScript<TViewModel>(this ViewPage<TViewModel> viewPage)
    {
        if (viewPage.ViewData["FieldToFocus"] == null)
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;

        object expression = viewPage.ViewData["FieldToFocus"];

        Type expressionType = expression.GetType(); // expressionType = Expression<Func<TViewModel, TProperty>>
        Type functionType = expressionType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // functionType = Func<TViewModel, TProperty>
        Type[] functionGenericArguments = functionType.GetGenericArguments(); // functionGenericArguments = [TViewModel, TProperty]
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = typeof(ViewPageExtensions).GetMethod("GetIdFor").MakeGenericMethod(functionGenericArguments); // method = GetIdFor<TViewModel, TProperty>

        MvcHtmlString id = (MvcHtmlString)method.Invoke(null, new[] { viewPage, expression }); // Call GetIdFor<TViewModel, TProperty>(viewPage, expression);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(
            @"<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#" + id + @"').focus();
                    }, 500);
                });
            </script>");
    }
}
```

Perhaps there's a more elegant way to do, but I think what it boils down to is you're trying to cast an object (ie return type of `ViewData["FieldToFocus"]`) to the correct expression tree `Expression<Func<TViewModel, TProperty>>` but like you've said you don't know what TProperty should be.

Also to make this work I had to add another static method to `GetIdFor` because at the moment I'm not too sure how to invoke an extension method. Its just a wrapper to call the `IdFor` extension method.

You could make it less verbose (but probably less readable).

```
object expression = viewPage.ViewData["FieldToFocus"];

MethodInfo method = typeof(ViewPageExtensions).GetMethod("GetIdFor")
    .MakeGenericMethod(expression.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetGenericArguments());

MvcHtmlString id = (MvcHtmlString)method.Invoke(null, new[] { viewPage, expression });
```

One final thought, would the output of `HtmlHelper.IdFor` ever differ from `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText`? I don't fully understand IdFor, and wonder if it will always give you a string that matches the property name.

```
ViewData["FieldToFocus"] = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(fieldExpression);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of your out of the box Metadata to provide you the property Id etc..

And then in your Extensions:

```
      public static MvcHtmlString FocusFieldFor<TModel, TValue>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        var fullPropertyName = html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(metadata.PropertyName);
      var jsonData = 
        @"<script type=""text/javascript"">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#" + fullPropertyName + @"').focus();
                }, 500);
            });
        </script>";

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(jsonData);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but since you're passing in the field name to your FocusOnField function, could you not also just pass the string of the field name as well which will be the default ID in the view then set a ViewData value?  Then your javascript could do something like...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    onload = focusonme;
    function focusonme() {
        var element = document.getElementById(@ViewData["FieldToFocus"]);
        element.focus();
    }

</script>
```

Maybe this isn't exactly what you're after, but the JS will definitely work this way...

Comment: I'm not passing the name of the field, I'm passing an expression. The point of passing the expression is so I don't have to hard-code the name of the field.